# UICollectionview cell is not appearing in same gap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing custom layout UICollectionview but I am seeing first row has different frame from second row. I want all cell come after ending with its previous cell.

```
     let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical //.horizontal
    layout.itemSize = CGSize.init(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40, height: 38)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
    self.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.collectionView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

    self.collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    layout.invalidateLayout()
```

[image]

Comment: Show the code for the custom layout.

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: And you want cells 4,5,6 to line up with cells 1,2, and 3?

Comment: if you want to left align items, try [UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout](https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout)